# Animate widget back to original position on gesture end

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm pretty new to Flutter and decided to challenge myself to implement Tinder-like swipe-able cards to get going. I used a gesture detector and transform widgets to handle moving and rotating the cards while the user drags which is working great. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly animate the card back to it's original position after the user lets go. I tried using a tween to animate between the cards offset and 0, but the animation doesn't work. Instead of a smooth animation the card snaps back instantly. Hope this is enough information for you guys. Let me know if I should provide anything else. Any help getting this fixed up would be awesome. Thanks!

Here's the code for my swiper:

```
class _SwiperState extends State<Swiper> with TickerProviderStateMixin{
  List<Widget> cardList;

  var xOffset = 0.0;
  var yOffset = 0.0;
  var dragStartx = 0.0;
  var dragStarty = 0.0;
  var width;

  AnimationController xAnimationController;
  AnimationController yAnimationController;
  Animation<double> xAnimation;
  Animation<double> yAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    xAnimationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    xAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: xOffset, end: 0).animate(xAnimationController);
    xAnimationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        xOffset = xAnimation.value;
      });
    });

    yAnimationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1));
    yAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: xOffset, end: 0).animate(yAnimationController);
    yAnimationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        yOffset = yAnimation.value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    xAnimationController.dispose();
    yAnimationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    List<ProfileCard> cards = new List();
    cards.add(ProfileCard(Colors.blue, 'Samantha'));
    cards.add(ProfileCard(Colors.red, 'Amanda'));
    cards.add(ProfileCard(Colors.indigo, 'Maria'));

    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: GestureDetector(
        onHorizontalDragDown: (drag) {
          setState(() {
            dragStartx = drag.globalPosition.dx;
            dragStarty = drag.globalPosition.dy;
          });
        },
        onHorizontalDragUpdate: (drag) {
          setState(() {
            xOffset = drag.globalPosition.dx - dragStartx;
            yOffset = drag.globalPosition.dy - dragStarty;
          });
          print('xOffset: $xOffset');
          print('yOffset: $yOffset');
        },
        onHorizontalDragEnd: (drag) {
          xAnimationController.forward(from: 0.0);
          yAnimationController.forward(from: 0.0);
        },
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(xOffset, yOffset),
          child: Transform.rotate(
            angle: xOffset / width / 2,
            child: Card(
              color: cards[0].color,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```